# Extend a rails model using another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm writing a gem that I want to extend a model. I tried defining the class in my gem as:

```
class UserModel < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and then the user model as:

```
class User < Adauth::UserModel
```

But this caused Active Record to throw up a table not found error as it was using UserModel not User for the model name.

I can't specify the the model name as I intend to have a named generator create the model with User as the default.

I'm assuming that it isnt possible to inherit from 2 classes/modules in the definition line so how would I import all the methods from Adauth::UserModel into a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution for your problem, but you could try using mixins.

Define a module UserModel with all the methods you want.

```
module Adauth
  module UserModel
    # methods go here
  end
end
```

and then when you define your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Adauth::UserModel
end
```